# DRF - OrderedDict in serialized object

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm having problems getting a nested ModelSerializer to be correctly serialized by Django rest framework. The nested serializer becomes an OrderedDict inside the parent JSON object.

I've played around with the Meta.depth value, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Creating a FileTypeSerializer on its own will result in a correctly formed JSON object.

Any suggestions?

Serializers:

```
class FileTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileType

class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='id'
    )
    filetype = FileTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = FileUpload
        read_only_fields = ('created', 'datafile', 'owner', 'filetype')
        depth = 1
```

Factories:

```
class FileTypeFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = FileType

    id = fuzzy.FuzzyInteger(1, 9999)
    name = fuzzy.FuzzyText(length=50)
    description = fuzzy.FuzzyText(length=200)

class FileUploadFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUpload

    id = fuzzy.FuzzyInteger(1, 9999)
    filetype = factory.SubFactory(FileTypeFactory)
    owner = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
```

Test:

```
fuf = FileUploadFactory()
serializer = FileUploadSerializer(instance=fuf, context=serializer_context)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Result:

```
(Pdb) serializer.data
{'owner': 185, 'filetype': OrderedDict([('id', 8855), ('name', u'dFokZyReaOcwCDjAVwxGYhZNVpgOZKeaKRaMWKKHxIDZxceUWr'), ('description', u'ZNOCugfyRaWPGGmfoqZEzoBLknRBVdXyXgYwIFKBJAVuQQKppTiGVMKfgjcjCiUlzmNGFLNQiHIiCEIpydCCtfoWnqrgKOlTZXfUeYLKZgNatsxrRXyWkAEkZmfBjvFFPXcBRshcqIyHMxgHjGjCDBPLJZnEevUXIRAfBnJiLQyHblHONZllglgXhzashLqCvzmNitfN')]), 'datafile': None, 'id': 4960, 'created': '2016-04-21'}
```

**Edit**

Sorry, should have probably been more specific with what the actuall problem is. The problem is that the response from

```
response = self.client.post(url, serializer.data, format='multipart')
```

says that "filetype" is a required field - i.e it is not beeing correctly jsonified or something.

Stepping deeper into the code of **post** (from django.test.Client), in **encode_multipart**

```
(Pdb) lines
['--BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"', '', '814', '--BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="owner"', '', '193', '--BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filetype"', '', 'id', '--BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filetype"', '', 'name', '--BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filetype"', '', 'description', '--BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="created"', '', '2016-04-21']
(Pdb) data
{'owner': 193, 'filetype': OrderedDict([('id', 1335), ('name', u'YdmXrMnxeXjzKxYhlLgaGClqTVMbTJIeMvWvQRLWUsVHWQQbFL'), ('description', u'YrmwBkwFhXGqWCNCjUIQdnBHaPQXqAhIXnOaycknMzFZPjWrWtrhYbWYBKdYDJWnRntPNjQranWjbwdBJPnKPLxAbWInfOrGZyGwDaMvlWCVMmylwxzPxCtMRkYJfuetQnvdbcheXQiRWqzFNfrKrWlcpSakmCmxFdsYBjnlxLByfulBBdiGqRdjOvkMxiUWDxasEgdT')]), 'datafile': None, 'id': 814, 'created': '2016-04-21'}
```

so it seems that the values of the filetype keys are not being encoded.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Once you call `json.dumps(serializer.data)` on the Object, the order will be forgotten (same as with most data types).

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear about that I see. I've updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
filetype = FileTypeSerializer(allow_empty_file=True,required=False)
```